# Geolocator PositionChanged event not firing for getting current location

Tags: c#, location, winrt-async

I am trying to get current location for WinRT application.
But PositionChanged event never gets fired.
Any help is highly appreciated !

In Package.appxmanifest, I have enabled Location.
My code is below:-

```
    Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator { ReportInterval = 2000 };
    geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 100;  // specify your range
    geolocator.PositionChanged += OnPositionChanged;

private async void OnPositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.previousLocationState == LocationStates.PopupEmpty && (viewModel.Coordinate == null || viewModel.Coordinate.Latitude != prevGpsCoordinate.Latitude || viewModel.Coordinate.Longitude != prevGpsCoordinate.Longitude))
            {
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    this.viewModel.Coordinate = new GpsCoordinate { Latitude = e.Position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude, Longitude = e.Position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude };
                    Field.GpsCoordinate gpsCoord = new Field.GpsCoordinate { Latitude = viewModel.Coordinate.Latitude, Longitude = viewModel.Coordinate.Longitude };
                    CreateMapPin(gpsCoord);
                    prevGpsCoordinate = this.viewModel.Coordinate;
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you called the static method RequestAccessAsync beforehand?

Comment: Hi @SteveJ
There is no method called RequestAccessAsync available in Geolocator class

Comment: It's static. You don't call it on the instance.

Comment: There is no such static method available... Only Equals and ReferenceEquals static methods are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this:

```
await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator { ReportInterval = 2000 };
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 100;  // specify your range
geolocator.PositionChanged += OnPositionChanged;
await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

Putting this as an answer because I can't post code in a comment.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 and I have set Location privacy setting as on.
var geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
This checks if i location is enabled. But getting exception as "Your App does not have permission to access location data. Make sure you have defined ID_CAP_LOCATION in the 
application manifest and that on your phone, you have turned on location by checking Settings > Location."

Comment: Can you add the section of the manifest where you enable location to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by putting this code in Package.appxmanifest

```
<DeviceCapability Name="location" />
```